# How to fix "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `calcularBeta1` method. When I run the program, I've got this error:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

```
 resultadoB1 = (sumaXY - ((sumaX * sumaY ) / totalElementos )) / (sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2) / totalElementos)
```

## Method calcularBeta1

```
def calcularBeta1(self, lista):
    actual = lista.nodoInicio
    sumaXY = 0
    sumaX = 0
    sumaY = 0
    sumaXCuadrada = 0
    totalElementos = 0
    while actual != None:
        dato1 = actual.dato1
        dato2 = actual.dato2
        sumaXY += dato1 * dato2
        sumaX += dato1
        sumaY += dato2
        sumaXCuadrada += math.pow(dato1, 2)
        totalElementos += 1
        actual = actual.siguienteNodo

    resultadoB1 = (sumaXY - ((sumaX * sumaY ) / totalElementos )) / (sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2) / totalElementos)
    return resultadoB1
```

## LecturaArchivo class

```
class LecturaArchivo:
   datosArchivo = ListaEnlazada()
   operaciones = Operaciones()
   xTemporal = 0
   yTemporal = 0


   nombreArchivo = input('Nombre del archivo: ')
   archivo = open(nombreArchivo, "r")
   lineas = archivo.read()
   datos = lineas.split(',')
   datoProxy = float(input('Proxy: '))

   while lineas:
      lineas = archivo.readlines()
      xTemporal = datos[0]
      yTemporal = datos[1]

      datosArchivo.agregarNodoFinal(float(xTemporal), float(yTemporal))
  print(datos)

  sumaElementos = sum(datosArchivo.obtenerNodos())
  mediaElementos = operaciones.media(sumaElementos, datosArchivo.tamano())
  beta1 = operaciones.calcularBeta1(datosArchivo)
  print('Beta1: ', beta1)
  beta0 = operaciones.calcularBeta0(beta1, media)
  print('Beta0: ', beta0)
  yk = operaciones.calcularYK(beta0, beta1, datoProxy)
  print('Regresión Líneal: ', yk)
```

Comment: fix: do not divide by zero. Your problem is data-derived - you do not provide data. How should we help? Show us what inputs lead to this problem.

Comment: On a afterthough .. even if you provided data .. if you calculations are correct there is not much you can do to prevent it - try: except: and invalidate that calculationif it leads to an error-

Comment: The problem is likely that `datosArchivo.nodoInicio` is None. You can't calculate Beta of an empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZeroDivisionError` happens when you try to divide a number by 0, which as you know is a mathematical impossibility, just change the value of the dividend.

Comment: Impossible in the reals. Produces positive or negative infinity in the extended reals.

Comment: Certainly not impossible according to the IEEE 754 floating point specification, which is what nearly all languages follow. Python is an outlier here.

Answer (score 1):

Python is unable to divide numbers by 0. If you ever attempt to divide by 0, python will throw a `ZeroDivisionError`, which is what happened to you. The best way to fix it is to just *not divide by zero*. You can use an `if` statement to ensure that the values are not zero.

Comment: I would not say "Python is unable" to divide by 0. Python implements the division correctly by saying it is impossible to divide by zero.

Comment: @zvone true, but python cannot divide by zero because it is impossible to divide by zero.

Comment: that is exactly my point ;) just wanted to make it clear that it is correct not to be able to do it

Comment: @zvone actually it is *incorrect* not to be able to do it. 1/(+0) is defined as +inf by the IEEE 754 specification. Python is an outlier in this case... nearly all programming languages follow this specification more closely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't divide by zero.

In the expression it complains about

```
resultadoB1 = (sumaXY - ((sumaX * sumaY ) / totalElementos )) / (sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2) / totalElementos)
```

it will be either `totalElementos` or the results of `sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2)` that are zero.

You'll need to add code to handle the possibility of those situations before trying to calculate that formula.

Comment: You mean the results of: (sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2) / totalElementos)

Comment: @J_Zoio The result of that division will only be zero if the numerator is zero.

Comment: @J_Zoio No, I wrote what I meant. If `sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2)` is zero then `sumaXCuadrada - math.pow(sumaX, 2) / totalElementos` will also be zero (assuming `totalElementos` is non-zero, but I already said that it being zero would also be a problem).